# Insert into two tables with Auto_inc foreign key MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-insert, auto-increment

This might be easier than i thought, but i just cant visualize the solution.

I have two tables that i want to insert data to with PHP.

```
Table1: ListID IDENTITY PK
        User
        date

Table2: ListID PK FK
        item   PK
        number
```

How can I do this in one transaction, getting the IDENTITY ID from table1 to table 2? In MS SQL.

Comment: Since you tagged your question sql-server, do you actually mean `identity` rather than `auto_increment`?

Comment: Yes. I meant identity. More familiar with mysql so a typo there.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `@@IDENTITY`, or `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to retrieve the id of the last inserted row.

```
begin transaction;
insert into table1(user, date) values(@user, @date);
insert into table2(listid, item, number) values(@@identity, @item, @number);
commit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefere SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead of @@identity.
You'll never know if you have some side effects (e.g. trigger) creating onother identity value in your session.

Comment: Wont the transaction lock the tables though?